Unable to get firebase OTP in Android Device, Log says app verification failed
Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
=> My app is not listed in the Play Store now get OTP before integrating Play Integrity or app check
=> I tried everything possible solution but getting the same issue
=> And please someone let me know how I disabled Recaptcha
com.jvm.parkar:63e26874: onRequestHide at ORIGIN_CLIENT_HIDE_SOFT_INPUT reason HIDE_SOFT_INPUT
2024-07-15 14:09:55.210 22693-23540 LocalRequestInterceptor com.jvm.parkar                       W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
2024-07-15 14:09:55.260 22693-23540 TrafficStats            com.jvm.parkar                       D  tagSocket(146) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-07-15 14:09:56.154 22693-23540 FirebaseAuth            com.jvm.parkar                       E  [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
2024-07-15 14:09:56.157 22693-22693 FirebaseAuth            com.jvm.parkar                       D  Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +919058425659, error - This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
2024-07-15 14:09:56.163 22693-22693 Verification Fragment   com.jvm.parkar                       W  onVerificationFailed (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzach.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:39)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadf.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzade.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@23.0.0:4)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:1000)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:242)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:362)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8448)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:992)


